# Concat files in reverse order

Tags: bash, shell

I need to concat multiple files to a single file in reverse order.

The order of lines in the files should not be changed.

For example:

```
file 1.txt
1
2
```

```
file 2.txt
3
4
```

The expected result:

```
result.txt
3
4
1
2
```

---

These command do not work as expected:

`tac *.txt > result.txt` just reverses the order of lines in the files and concat the files in ordinal order. (`2 1 4 3`)

`cat $(ls -r) > result.txt` or `ls -r | xargs cat > result.txt` do not work if filenames have a space character:

```
cat: file: No such file or directory
cat: 2.txt: No such file or directory
cat: file: No such file or directory
cat: 1.txt: No such file or directory
```

The problem is that while `ls -r` returns `'file 2.txt'  'file 1.txt'`, but `echo $(ls -r)` returns `file 2.txt file 1.txt` that looks like four files for `cat`.

---

Comment: I have a lot of files.

Comment: Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: Using of `xargs` with `-0` leads to `cat: 'result.txt'$'\n''file 2.txt'$'\n''file 1.txt'$'\n': No such file or directory`. I'm interested in a short command.

Comment: That error sounds like you forgot a `-print0` in `find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no short one line command that can be easily be typed from memory.
It makes sense to create a function and put it into `.bashrc` file.

[pjh's recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66755554/11468937) works inappropriate slow.
So I wrote this one:

```sh
function revcat {
  for item in "$@"; do
    echo "$item"; 
  done | tac | xargs -d"\n" cat;
}
```

It works like `cat`, but with the expected, reversed, file concatenation order.

For example: `revcat *.txt > out.txt`.

Answer (score 5):

Great - so first list **the filenames**, then reverse their order, then cat them.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | sort -r | xargs -d'\n' cat
```

And similar with filename expansion, that is sorted by itself:

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | tac | xargs -d'\n' cat
```

To be fullproff against newlines in filenames, use zero separated streams - `printf "%s\0"` `find .. -print0` `xargs -0` `tac -s ''`.

Remember [do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Comment: Not so short as I wanted, but works. Btw, `printf "'%s' " *.txt | tac | xargs cat` also works. But not this `cat $(printf "'%s' " *.txt | tac)`.

Comment: I see no value in `printf "'%s' " *.txt | tac | xargs` and it will break when the filename has `'` or `"` in it's name.

Comment: Could you write a `revcat` function in your answer like it did pjh, but without recursion? His function works, but significantly slow. I think it would be useful not only for me, just put the function to `.bashrc` and use it later like `cat`, without need to copy'n'paste the long command every time.

Comment: Can't you do it yourself? Why do you need me to write `revcat() { stuff here }` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (recursive) function:

```
function revcat
{
    (( $# == 0 )) && return 0
    revcat "${@:2}"
    cat -- "$1"
}
```

Example usage:

```
revcat *.txt
```

Comment: Nice. I just added it to `.bashrc` file _(`%HOMEPATH%/.bashrc`. I use Git Bash.)_. So only I need to type `revcat *.txt > out.txt` now.

Comment: But it works **very slow**. It takes 12 second to concat 256 files. Each file is less than 1 KB. `cat` does it instantly.